# Any complete subset of normed vector space is closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification, vector-spaces

Consider a normed vector space $(V,\lVert \cdot \rVert)$. Need to show that if $S\subseteq V$ is complete then $S$ is closed.

My approach:

A complete subset $S$ of $V$ satisfies that any sequence contained entirely in $S$ converges to a point in $S$, with respect to $\lVert \cdot \rVert$. Suppose $V$ is open. Then there exists a point $x\in V\backslash S$ such that $x$ is a limit point of $S$. But this contradicts the above definition. Hence, $V$ must be closed.

Please let me know if this approach is correct.

Comment: The correct assumption to begin a proof of the contrapositive would be that $S$ is non-closed, not that $S$ is open (I think you’ve mixed up $S$ and $V$).

I also think you are doing yourself a disservice by proving the contrapositive. Closedness is more or less contained in the very definition of completeness.

Comment: Your definition of complete is wrong.  $S$ is complete if any **Cauchy** sequence has a limit in $S$.

Comment: @Hayden, since $S$ is complete, if a sequence converges in $S$, it must be a Cauchy sequence, correct? Also, if $S$ is complete, then $V$ is necessarily complete, is this true?

Comment: @sequence The way you wrote it is "any sequence contained entirely in $S$ converges to a point in $S$".  In other words, you said any sequence converges, which isn't true.  To answer your questions, yes to the first, no to the second.

Comment: @Hayden, since $S$ is complete, if a sequence converges in $S$, it must be a Cauchy sequence. This would imply that, if $S$ is not closed, then $\exists x$, a limit point of $S$, which is in $V\backslash S$, and thus the sequence $\{x_n\}\subset S$ converging to $x$ must be a Cauchy sequence converging to $x\not\in S$, a contradiction. Thus $S$ must be closed.
But I think that there could be a flaw... Namely, if a sequence contained in $S$ converges to $x$, it does not have to be a Cauchy sequence, since it does not converge in $S$. Do you think this is correct?

Comment: @sequence While not incorrect, you keep saying "if a sequence *converges in $S$*...".  But you don't need this assumption.  If it converges at all, it is Cauchy.  This is an important distinction if you're trying to talk about points which are outside of $S$, as you are doing.

Comment: @Hayden, since $S$ is complete, if a sequence contained entirely in $S$ is convergent, it must be a Cauchy sequence. This would imply that, if $S$ is not closed, then $\exists x$, a limit point of $S$, which is in $V\backslash S$, and thus the sequence $\{x_n\}\subset S$ converging to $x$ must be a Cauchy sequence converging to $x\not\in S$, a contradiction. Thus $S$ must be closed.
I think this should now be correct :)

Comment: @sequence Yes, that sounds much better.  As in my answer below, you can also proceed without doing it by contradiction at all, but the flavor of the proof doesn't change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose $S\subset V$ is complete. If $x$ is a limit point of $S$, then there is a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \subset S$ converging to $x$.  But $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is thus Cauchy, so by the completeness hypothesis, converges *inside of $S$*.  In other words, $x\in S$, so $S$ is closed.

(Note that nothing is special about being in a normed space here; this works for any metric space $(V,d)$.)

Comment: Hi, how did you conclude that S is closed in the end  of the proof? @Hayden can you state the theory?

Comment: A set is closed if and only if it contains its limit points. In the context of normed vector spaces, which are metric spaces and hence first-countable, this is the same as saying that a set $F$ is closed if and only if for every convergent sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of elements of $F$, the limit of $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ lies in $F$.

Comment: Yeah, so in your answer above, you assumed that $x\in V$ right? @Hayden

Comment: Yes; if you were to talk about elements outside of $V$, then you'd be working in a bigger structure. The question here is about subsets of $V$, so its topology is the only thing that matters (in particular, 'limit points' means 'limit points in $V$').